# IndexStats Query in DocumentDB returning 0 ops

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, go, mongodb-query, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to build a Documentdb Prometheus exporter. I'm trying to get the IndexStats to identify the unused Indices. But I'm getting **ops** value as 0 even though the **ops** value is not 0. Can you please help me identify the error?

This the Go code for the same.

```
databases, err := client.ListDatabaseNames(ctx, bson.D{})

    if err != nil{
        return make(map[string]map[string]interface{}), err
    }

    var indexMap map[string]map[string]interface{} = make(map[string]map[string]interface{})
    for _, database := range databases {
        collections, err := client.Database(database).ListCollectionNames(ctx, bson.D{})

        if err != nil {
            return make(map[string]map[string]interface{}), err
        }

        for _, collectionName := range collections {

            collection := client.Database(database).Collection(collectionName)
            indexStats := bson.D{{Key: "$indexStats", Value: bson.M{}}}
            cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{indexStats})
            if err != nil {
                return make(map[string]map[string]interface{}), err
            }
        
            var indices []bson.M

            err = cursor.All(ctx, &indices)

            if err != nil {
               return make(map[string]map[string]interface{}), err
            }

            err = cursor.Close(ctx)

            if err != nil {
               return make(map[string]map[string]interface{}), err
            }

            fmt.Print(database + " " + collectionName + " ")
            fmt.Println(indices)
            indicesBytes, err := json.Marshal(indices)
        
            if err != nil {
                return make(map[string]map[string]interface{}), err
            }
                
            var indicesJson []interface{}
        
            err = json.Unmarshal(indicesBytes, &indicesJson)
        
            if err != nil {
                return make(map[string]map[string]interface{}), err
            }
            if _, ok := indexMap[database];  !ok {
                indexMap[database] = make(map[string]interface{})
            }

            indexMap[database][collectionName] = indicesJson

        }

    }
```

May I know the reason and the fix for this issue?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: First try handling all errors, the least you can do is log it if it occurs. E.g. `cursor.All()`, `cursor.Close()` return errors.

Comment: Have Updated the code and Printing the error message as well(in other function).

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: It's not working intermittently for me. Not sure what is the issue.I have tried adding delays between queries even that didn't work.